# How to design Mysql table that manages the cross ranking between group A and B?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Ok, here is the company requirement.

The Company A has 2 Group A & B. Group A has N number of people & Group B has M number of people.

Each person in each group will rank a level from 1 to 5 for maximum of 5 people in the opposite group.

Each person may not rank anyone or rank less than 5 people.

A person in a group must not rank a same level to different people  to other group. That mean each level out of 5 levels must go with its own person, thus each level must not go with 2 different people.

After all people did their ranking. Then The manager checks the winning Pair in the 1st round. If a person in a group ranks a level for other person in other group and in turn that other person ranks the same person with the same level will be the winning Pair.

After that the Group A and B continue to rank but this time the system should remove the winning pair in the 1st round to out of the list.

So Here is what I design mysql DB.

```
GroupA Table
groupAPersonID - ranking level - groupBPersonID - roundNo - winningPair
1              - 1             - 3              - 1       - y
1              - 2             - 2              - 1     
1              - 3             - 4              - 1     
1              - 4             - 1              - 1
1              - 5             - 8              - 1     
2              - 1             - 2              - 1     
2              - 2             - 3              - 1     
2              - 3             - 5              - 1     
2              - 4             - 8              - 1
2              - 5             - 8              - 1 ---> illegal record cos groupBPersonID "8" has 2 Level 4 & 5

GroupB Table
groupBPersonID - ranking level - groupAPersonID - roundNo - winningPair
1              - 1             - 6              - 1     
1              - 2             - 4              - 1     
1              - 3             - 5              - 1     
1              - 4             - 1              - 1
1              - 5             - 8              - 1     
3              - 1             - 1              - 1       - Y     
3              - 2             - 2              - 1     
3              - 3             - 8              - 1     
3              - 4             - 3              - 1
3              - 4             - 6              - 1 --> illegal record cos the Level 4 that was rankled by groupBPersonID "3" appears 2 times
```

Note: groupAPersonID "1" & groupBPersonID "3" are the winning pair cos groupAPersonID "1" ranked the Level 1 for groupBPersonID "3" & groupBPersonID "3" ranked the Level 1 for groupAPersonID "1". So groupAPersonID "1" & groupBPersonID "3" must not appear in 2nd round.

```
GroupA Table
groupAPersonID - ranking level - groupBPersonID - roundNo - winningPair
...continue from the about data...
2              - 1             - 2              - 2     
2              - 2             - 3              - 2 --> illegal record cos  groupBPersonID "3" won the first round    
2              - 3             - 5              - 2   

GroupB Table
groupBPersonID - ranking level - groupAPersonID - roundNo - winningPair
...continue from the about data...
3              - 2             - 4              - 2 --> illegal record cos  groupBPersonID "3" won the first round    
1              - 2             - 1              - 2 --> illegal record cos  groupAPersonID "1" won the first round
```

If i design by 2 tables like this then I need to control the inserted record at programming level as user can insert the illegal record.

I am not sure my design is ok.

Can you come up with other elegant design to mange this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is not normalized, so I would start with combining those two tables in one like this:

```
EmployeeRanks
-------------
FromPersonId
ToPersonID
Ranking
Round
```

And create a new table that will match employees to groups:

```
GroupEmployees 
---------------
Group
PersonId
```

Comment: but how to control the illegal records?

Comment: I guess you should control it before it gets to the database. Otherwise calculate it on the fly.